# having multiple server name with nginx

Tags: nginx

I need to support few server names like:

```
ab1
ab2
ab3
abc
```

so the last letter can change I thought of having

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name ab?;
        return 200 "i'm the server";
}
```

is this correct? how can I test it?

thanks

Comment: Why do you need to have a server name? `listen 80 default_server;` will work for any server name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should work, since [nginx supports regex in server_name directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)
You can even capture the letter like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name ~^ab(.)$;
        return 200 "i'm the server $1";
}
```

Comment: It should be `~^ab.$`

Comment: You're totally right